# Can I combine constructors in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    public AccountService(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, string dataSourceID)
    {
        this._modelState = modelStateDictionary;
        this._accountRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Account>(dataSourceID);
        this._productRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Product>(dataSourceID);
    }

    public AccountService(string dataSourceID)
    {
        this._accountRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Account>(dataSourceID);
        this._productRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Product>(dataSourceID);
    }
```

Is there some way that I can simplify the constructors so each doesn't have to do the StorageHelper calls?

Also do I need to specify this.  ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
public AccountService(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, string dataSourceID)
    : this(dataSourceID)
{
    this._modelState = modelStateDictionary;

}
```

This will first call your other constructor. You can also use `base(...` to call a base constructor.

`this` in this case is implied.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you have a couple of choices:

1) Abstract the common initialization logic into another method and call that from each constructor. You would need this method if you needed to control the order in which items are initialized (i.e. if _modelState requires _accountRepository to be initialized after it):

```
public AccountService(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, string dataSourceID)
{
    this._modelState = modelStateDictionary;
    Initialize(dataSourceID);
}

public AccountService(string dataSourceID)
{
    Initialize(dataSourceID);
}

private void Initialize(string dataSourceID) 
{
    this._accountRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Account>(dataSourceID);
    this._productRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Product>(dataSourceID);
}
```

2) Cascade the constructors by adding `this` at the end:

```
public AccountService(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, string dataSourceID) : this(dataSourceID)
{
    this._modelState = modelStateDictionary;
}

public AccountService(string dataSourceID)
{
    this._accountRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Account>(dataSourceID);
    this._productRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Product>(dataSourceID);
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm. Which of the "this" words if any could I remove?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking, but if you are asking about the `this._` code, you can remove all of them. For example, `this._accountRepository` can also be written as `_accountRepository`. The `this` I was referring to is on the same line as the constructor declaration (scroll all the way to the right to see it).

Comment: @RichardM: Pretty much all of them.  `this.` can nearly always be inferred within context, unless you're passing in a variable with the same name.  Some people like it, citing readability (more explicit).  Others dislike it for the same reason (redundant information).

Comment: +1 BTW.  Also, abstracting the initialization to its own method is good if you are very picky about initialization order of the items that are common between constructors (e.g. it should always come last).  If you're not as picky, or the common initialization should happen first, it is better to place that initialization in one constructor and just have others defer to it.  You get the same readability, and get to implement one less method (which helps readability slightly).  Take these "rules" with salt.  I'd always go with what was most natural for the scenario